# Почему тень перекрывает блок, который она не должна перекрывать?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, scss

У меня тень шапки перекрывает выплывающую меню,
подскажите плиз, почему?

У самой шапки которая перекрывает - position: fixed;
У выдвижной меню - position: absolute относительно верхнего прямоугольника с надписью 'каталог товаров'.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: z-index погуглите.

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте поставить на всплывающее меню z-index выше чем чем у шапки.

Comment: Неправильный ответ. Автор спрашивает `Почему?`, а не `Что делать?`. ))

Comment: логично)) спасибо))

Comment: пробовал, не работает